# complexity of classical counting algorithm

Tags: complexity-theory

Does anyone know the solution of Exercise 6.14 of Nielsen and Cheung:

> Prove that any classical counting algorithm with a probability at least
>   3/4 for estimating $M$ correctly to within an accuracy $c \sqrt{M}$ for some constant $c$
>   and for all values of $M$ must make $\Omega(N)$ oracle calls.

The same result is also stated in Mosca's phd thesis in Table 2.5 but with no references where this is proved.

Mosca's phd thesis cites

> Ran Canetti, Guy Even, and Oded Goldreich. Lower bounds for sampling algorithms for estimating the average. Information Processing Letters, 1995.

and

> Goldreich, Oded. "A sample of samplers: A computational perspective on sampling." Studies in Complexity and Cryptography. Miscellanea on the Interplay between Randomness and Computation. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg, 2011. 302-332.

but from those I see a complexity of $\Omega(M)$ not $\Omega(N)$

Comment: Might be related and maybe helpful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2888407/lower-bounds-for-classical-counting-algorithm